# How can i set the tabhost to only take up some max width and height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I am trying add a tabhost in my application. So far I have gotten part of it done (for some reason the content does not show up but ill fix that later). But is it possible (without adding like another 3 container and margining like crazy) to make sure that the tabhost does not take up too much space on the screen or does it have to take up the whole screen unless margins are used

current way I have it

|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
|     header

|tabbar

|tabcontent

|tabcontent

|**__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

but centered

The way I want it

|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
|     header

|tabbar          |    a pic

|tabcontent    |           a pic

|tabcontent     |          a pic

|**__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

tha a pic is just a picture that takes up the whole space on the right

Is something like this possible with just manipulating the tabhost? or is the tabhost a full screen thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was some weird work with my xml before but It is possible. I am using a LinearLayout and the picture to the right its weight is 1. Then below is how I have set up the tabhost to allow it to be only a height and width that wraps its content.

```
 <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="125dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
```

This has worked for me, hope it helps someone else.